# match category and parent category in xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm new to using xml in php. I need to match categories and parent category in my xml file. I couldn't figure it out what is the best way to do that. Output style is not important, i just need to see it as text-based tree-view or something else.

Here is little example of my xml and output:

```
<Categories><Category>
<Id>100</Id>
<Name>Cars</Name>
<ParentCategoryId>0</ParentCategoryId>
</Category>

<Category>
<Id>150</Id>
<Name>Ferrari</Name>
<ParentCategoryId>100</ParentCategoryId>
</Category>

<Category>
<Id>151</Id>
<Name>Ford</Name>
<ParentCategoryId>100</ParentCategoryId>
</Category>

<Category>
<Id>176</Id>
<Name>Mustang</Name>
<ParentCategoryId>151</ParentCategoryId>
</Category>


<Category>
<Id>177</Id>
<Name>Focus</Name>
<ParentCategoryId>151</ParentCategoryId>
</Category>


<Category>
<Id>101</Id>
<Name>Planes</Name>
<ParentCategoryId>0</ParentCategoryId>
</Category>

<Category>
<Id>188</Id>
<Name>Boeing</Name>
<ParentCategoryId<101</ParentCategoryId>
</Category>
</Categories>
```

Output (what i need)

```
-Cars
--Ferrari
--Ford
---Mustang
---Focus
-Planes
--Boeing
```

Any idea would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml_parse_into_struct (http://php.net/manual/de/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php) to convert you xml into an key-based array.

Then loop the array with foreach and generate the output you'll need by filtering the elements.